# Android App Development in multiple languages

Tags: java, android, multilingual

I am developing one Android application in three languages named English,Spanish and German.First I completed development in English and wish to complete it in other two languages. Here my question is:

**Can I use the same code of Android project(which is in english) in the other two languages with different package names in the same project ?**.

Please help me with the sample code/links.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

of course you can. Follow these steps

1. make sure all of your strings through the application are listed as a resource in yourAppFolder/res/values/strings.xml and that you use strings in your app only via `getString(R.string.myString1)` and **NEVER** via hard-coded strings in your activities
2. create a new folder for each language you want to localize your app with the following syntax: for germany, values-de
3. copy the strings.xml file in the new folder you just created
4. translate each string in the file into your desired language

Now android OS will use the proper language based on the device's locale.

I bet that you don't fulfill requirement #1 and that will be the most of your work to do. At least that was happened to me in my first real android app ;)

Comment: yeah... if i develop the app in the way u suggested.. we get only one apk file for all the languages... but i want to get three different apks. my question is can i use the same java files and layouts in the three different project folders without copying those files...

Comment: why do you want multiple APKs? it would be an hassle to fix and mantain and upgrade your app when you will need it!